# HTML Containers Going Over the Page

Tags: html, css, django

I am relatively new to HTML but am getting a weird result from my django app. I have outlined what I have vs. what I'm looking for below for reference. As you can see by my code, the only places that I have called out a height is in that iframe which is pushing down the rest of the contents outside of container two. Container one is also purposed to extend the entire height of the page (that's just a side bar) and there should be some padding at the bottom of the page after the last container.

Any idea why this is happening?

HTML

```
<div class="float-container">  <!--Contents-->

  <div class="one"> <!--Left Panel-->

<ul class="list-group"> <!--Section Selection-->
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1:7000/polls" style="color:black">Page 1</a>
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    Page 2
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    Page 3
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    Page 4
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
  </li>
</ul> 
  <div class="two" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px">

   <h1 style="font-size: 24px; color: black; padding-left: 15px;padding-top: 55px;padding-bottom:5px">Stakeholder Mapping</h1>

<!--Visualization Card-->
   <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Visualizations
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 20px">Power BI</h1>
          <p class="card-text">NOTE: Power BI Pro is required to view this data. If visuals do not appear, this means that you do not have a Pro license</p>
          <iframe width="1220" height="1241" src="x" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>        
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="card">
       <div class="card-header">
           Data
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
           <h1 style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 20px">Raw Data</h1>
           <p class="card-text">description</p>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary badge-pill float-right" style="font-size: 14px; width:80px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">+ New</button>
               </div>
           </div>
           <br>

           <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'polls:search' %}">
               <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="search">
               <button class="btn btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"> Search </button>
           </form>
           <br>


           <table class="table table-hover" style="width:90% ">
               <thead>
                   <tr style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 14px">
                       <th scope="col">#</th>
                       <th scope="col">Employee</th>
                       <th scope="col">Stakeholder Group</th>
                       <th scope="col">Quadrant</th>
                       <th scope="col">Description</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   {% for stakeholder in stakeholder_list %}
                   <tr style="font-family: Graphik;font-size: 12px">
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.id }}</td>
                       <td style="font-size: 15px">{{ stakeholder.employee }}</td>
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_group }}</td>
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_quadrant }}</td>
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.description }}</td>
                       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
                   </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
           </table>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="float:left">Export to Excel</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

style.css

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(233, 236, 239);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.one {
  width: 15%;
  background:white;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  margin-left: 15%;
  background:  rgb(233, 236, 239);
}
```

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image: Desired State## Heading ##]

Comment: I suggest you dont use the ancient float technique that was never supposed to be sued as stylign emthod in the first place. Use some modern approach like CSS-Grid or flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the extra HTML context to your question. Soneav's CSS should work properly once you fix the errors in your HTML.

The error, like Soneav mentioned, includes needing a closing div tag. I would recommend getting HTML IntelliSense in your text editor (especially if you are using VSCode) so your text editor can point out unclosed tags.

Below is your HTML code with the missing tags filled in

```html
<div class="float-container">
    <!--Contents-->

    <div class="one">
        <!--Left Panel-->

        <ul class="list-group">
            <!--Section Selection-->
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a href="http://127.0.0.1:7000/polls" style="color:black">Page 1</a>
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                Page 2
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                Page 3
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                Page 4
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div> <!-- missing closing tag added -->

    <div class="two" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px">

        <h1 style="font-size: 24px; color: black; padding-left: 15px;padding-top: 55px;padding-bottom:5px">
            Stakeholder Mapping</h1>

        <!--Visualization Card-->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Visualizations
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 20px">Power BI</h1>
                <p class="card-text">NOTE: Power BI Pro is required to view this data. If visuals do not appear,
                    this means that you do not have a Pro license</p>
                <iframe width="1220" height="1241" src="x" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Data
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 20px">Raw Data</h1>
                <p class="card-text">description</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary badge-pill float-right"
                            style="font-size: 14px; width:80px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">+
                            New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'polls:search' %}">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="search">
                    <button class="btn btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"> Search </button>
                </form>
                <br>


                <table class="table table-hover" style="width:90% ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 14px">
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Employee</th>
                            <th scope="col">Stakeholder Group</th>
                            <th scope="col">Quadrant</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for stakeholder in stakeholder_list %}
                        <tr style="font-family: Graphik;font-size: 12px">
                            <td>{{ stakeholder.id }}</td>
                            <td style="font-size: 15px">{{ stakeholder.employee }}</td>
                            <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_group }}</td>
                            <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_quadrant }}</td>
                            <td>{{ stakeholder.description }}</td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill"
                                    style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="float:left">Export to Excel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- missing closing tag added -->
</div> <!-- missing closing tag added -->
```

Comment: Additional HTML context added - sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ife Lawal there are parts of your code that have not been included that would help better understand the problem. However I think I have a general idea of what you are looking for and you can compare the below to your own to help get a better understanding.
**Note** I have adjusted your iframe heights etc for easier viewing, you can just adjust those as needed:

For the HTML:

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="one">This will be the block on the left</div>

    <div class="two">
      <div class="card">
        <iframe width="1220" height="250" src="x"></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="card">This is the next card block</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {  
 width: 100%;
 background: #203864;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
}

.one {
 width: 15%; /* adjust as needed */
 background-color: #4472c4;
 margin-right: 2%; /* adjust as needed, space between one and two */
 padding: 2%; /* adjust as needed, inner space */
 color: white; /* adjust as needed, text colour */
}

.two {
 width:100%; /* adjust as needed */
 padding: 2%; /* adjust as needed , inner space*/
 background-color: #4472c4;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
 background-color: #9dc3e6;
 margin: 2% auto;  /* adjust as needed */
 padding: 2%; /* adjust as needed */
 width: 100%; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

the below will allow you to adjust the styling for the iframe box directly if you wanted

```
 .card iframe {width:100%; background:#ccc; }
```

**Edits:** apologies my original post was missing a div tag - I have fixed the error and tidied up the code

Comment: Additional HTML context added - sorry about that!

Comment: Hmm I added in your adjustments to the CSS file but am still getting the same issue. Any thoughts based on the additional context for the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing  tag after the ul and before two see below:

```
</ul> 

 </div><!-- Missing a closing tag you will need to add this to your code -->

<div class="two" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px">
```

I will look through the rest in a bit